# Apache htaccess Request exceeded the limit of internal redirects

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using htaccess for language switching. So that something like /en/mypage goes to /mypage?language=en

And /mypage then goes to say account.php

I found this line to add at the very bottom of htaccess that will switch back to the site's default language - in this case Swedish - when the URL is changed to /mypage

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?language=sv [L,QSA]
```

Do I care about non-existant URLs? mysite.som/randomurl doesn't redirect to any specific page, so I think it then loops because of above rule until Apache internal redirect limit is reached.

Is there some way to stop the loop after the first $1?language=sv ? Is there something like this that might help:

```
RewriteCond {%QUERY_STRING} language=sv
RewriteRule .* my404.php [L,R=404]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1?language=sv [L,QSA]
```

Would that stop it on the second attempt maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^language=$
RewriteRule .* 404.php [L,R=404]
```

Since for switching languages it will always at first have ?language=en or ?language=sv

If no ?language= is set, then last rule will switch to default (Swedish). If any language is set and no other rules found a page to go to, 404 them.